# InternalServerError when accessing image/sticker and code snippet urls in chat messages returned from Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I received "InternalServerError" when accessing an image/sticker/code-snippet link in a chat message return from Microsoft Graph Api.

I received the following chat message from Graph Api (not all properties are not listed):

```
{
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "<div><div><img alt=\"Sticker image, OH YEAH!\" src=\"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/2bf9ebf9-8c85-474a-818a-793bc8898757/channels/19:accc034188164562b194965de5f72d3b@thread.skype/messages/1561440945248/hostedContents/aWQ9eF8wLXNhLWQ4LTUxMTExNzY5OWQ4ZTg3YjgwMWUyMDA0ODVlODRkYThmLHR5cGU9MSx1cmw9aHR0cHM6Ly9hcy1hcGkuYXNtLnNreXBlLmNvbS92MS9vYmplY3RzLzAtc2EtZDgtNTExMTE3Njk5ZDhlODdiODAxZTIwMDQ4NWU4NGRhOGYvdmlld3MvaW1nbw==/$value\" style=\"width:334px; height:250px\"><img alt=\"Sticker image, WORKS ON MY MACHINE\" src=\"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/2bf9ebf9-8c85-474a-818a-793bc8898757/channels/19:accc034188164562b194965de5f72d3b@thread.skype/messages/1561440945248/hostedContents/aWQ9eF8wLXNhLWQ4LTNlYzQxOTFhYjYxODE5NTI1N2Y1YmVmOGI5YjdiY2JmLHR5cGU9MSx1cmw9aHR0cHM6Ly9hcy1hcGkuYXNtLnNreXBlLmNvbS92MS9vYmplY3RzLzAtc2EtZDgtM2VjNDE5MWFiNjE4MTk1MjU3ZjViZWY4YjliN2JjYmYvdmlld3MvaW1nbw==/$value\" style=\"width:375px; height:250px\"></div>\n\n\n</div>"
    },
}
```

Then I tried to access the image link

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/2bf9ebf9-8c85-474a-818a-793bc8898757/channels/19:accc034188164562b194965de5f72d3b@thread.skype/messages/1561440945248/hostedContents/aWQ9eF8wLXNhLWQ4LTUxMTExNzY5OWQ4ZTg3YjgwMWUyMDA0ODVlODRkYThmLHR5cGU9MSx1cmw9aHR0cHM6Ly9hcy1hcGkuYXNtLnNreXBlLmNvbS92MS9vYmplY3RzLzAtc2EtZDgtNTExMTE3Njk5ZDhlODdiODAxZTIwMDQ4NWU4NGRhOGYvdmlld3MvaW1nbw==/$value

Headers:
Authorization: bearer [access_token]
```

The response was:

```
500 Internal Server Error
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Failed to process request.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "83da292c-f982-44d3-ae07-ce8b10910b65",
            "date": "2019-06-25T08:09:35"
        }
    }
}

Headers:
request-id: 83da292c-f982-44d3-ae07-ce8b10910b65
client-request-id: 83da292c-f982-44d3-ae07-ce8b10910b65
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Southeast Asia","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_7","ADSiteName":"SEA"}}
Date: Tue, 25 Jun 2019 08:09:34 GMT
```

There are 2 images in the chat message. Accessing the other image incurred the same error.

However, if the chat message had only one image, the link worked. If the chat message had more than one images, or more specifically, more than one links to `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/[group_id]/channels/[channel_id]/messages/[message_id]/hostedContents/[content_id]/$value`, should it be an image or a code snippet, accessing the links returned me InternalServerError.

Can someone help?

Comment: This is resolved. Could you please try it at your end and confirm?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Thanks! I've tried it and it is working fine now!